# Visual Studio tag closing autocomplete not working

Tags: php, html, visual-studio, autocomplete

I have problem with visual studio shortcuts

When I type `<header>` in .html file, VS autocomplete the closing tag with `</header>`
But in file with .php extension it doesnt work.

I have installed every extension for VS that I have found by googling, but still did not succeed

`<?php` tag not working too, I have to type manually closing tags

Even when I click on suggested tags like this:
[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5alRr.png)

It does nothing